# What is the usage of componentsProps in Material-UI components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, components

I have seen this `componentsProps` in the API documentation of components such as `AutoComplete`, `StepLabel`, `BackDrop`, etc...., I didn't get any best example and perfect definition of the prop.

Anyone please explain it with basic and simple example in easy words that when, why and how it is used!

Comment: Can you link to the specific components as an example? Material-ui just recently went through a major version bump (v4 -> v5).

Comment: @DrewReese https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#main-content

Comment: Yes, "The props used for each slot inside." is a most unhelpful description, especially since I see no other reference to what "slots" are. Generally I read this as a `props` object that would be passed on to any passed render functions/components that you don't handle directly but may want to pass additional props to. You may need to spend some time digging through the source to see how each component handles them (*from what I can see `componentsProps` aren't consistent across components*).

Comment: @DrewReese I need to study the documentations of props inside the source code ?

Comment: Isn't source code the best documentation what the code is doing? I'm surprised by the number of times I've found undocumented behavior and props *just* from taking a dive into a project's/library's source code. Sometimes it's saved me from horrendous workarounds for an issue with using said project/library.

Comment: See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zx96j?file=/demo.js) which showcases the conversion of `styled` `Tooltip` to `sx` `Tooltip`. The `componentsProps` has been used in the later one to change the background color of the `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 5):

MUI exposes `componentsProps` on some components to let you override the props of the inner components. Specifically:

- In `Autocomplete` component, it's used to override the `AutocompleteClearIndicator` [props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/742ed168f8d920069bbc1dbaa38b41a86eb0a484/packages/mui-material/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L541-L541).
- In `StepLabel`, it's used to override the label [component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/742ed168f8d920069bbc1dbaa38b41a86eb0a484/packages/mui-material/src/StepLabel/StepLabel.js#L169-L169) (exclude the icon). Also note that the API is not inconsistent as [@Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69341536/what-is-the-usage-of-componentsprops-in-material-ui-components#comment122559251_69341536) pointed out, you can only override the label props with `componentsProps`, but to override the icon props, you have to use `StepIconProps` [prop](https://github.dev/mui-org/material-ui/blob/742ed168f8d920069bbc1dbaa38b41a86eb0a484/packages/mui-material/src/StepLabel/StepLabel.js#L160-L160) instead.
- In some other components like [`Menu`](https://mui.com/api/menu/), there is no `componentsProp` but `TransitionProps` and `MenuListProps` props to override the components inside individually.

Unfortunately, because there the prop is untyped (all marked as `object`), and there is no mention anywhere else in the docs. You have to dive into the source code to know what the `componentsProps` in a specific component does.

Below is the example of the `Autocomplete` component with the clear indicator removed. Note that you can do that with `disableClearable` in `Autocomplete`, this is just an example to demonstrate how the `componentsProp` can potentially be useful:

```
<Autocomplete
  componentsProps={{
    clearIndicator: {
      sx: {
        display: "none"
      }
    }
  }}
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: is this what they mean when referring to 'slots'?

Comment: @ortonomy I was wondering the same thing and found this.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Slot 